# How do I convert the following data sent from this function into a DataTable for the Google Charts API?

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, ajax

How can I convert the data sent by the following function into a DataTable that can be used in the Google Charts API?

```
public function ajax_get_dates(){
    $data = ([['date1' => '04/08/2016'], ['date2' => '05/08/2016'], ['date3' => '06/08/2016']]);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

I have tried the following through a successful Ajax call, but the data isn't being output onto the chart.

```
success: function(result) {
    data = new google.visualization.DataTable(result);
    data.addColumn('string', 'date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'date_value');
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't appear that google table will work with the format of the data you provided. The following will convert your format into one that will work. This may not be the prettiest approach, but the resulting format will work.

```
$data = ([['date1' => '04/08/2016'], ['date2' => '05/08/2016'], ['date3' => '06/08/2016']]);
$return_data = "";
foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
    foreach($value as $inner_key => $inner_value)
    {
        $return_data .= "['{$inner_key}','{$inner_value}'], ";
    }
}
echo $return_data;
```